# Regex expression to not include numbers in search

Tags: regex

I am trying to do a find replace all with a text editing tool with regex support and I dont know how to search for all of:

```
<a
name=Check51>
```

and

```
<a
name=Check52>
```

and so on.

there a alot I need to find like this and replace but am not experienced in regex syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
<a\r?\nname=Check\d+>
```

That will match that anchor tag with any number after `Check`. Also only if there is a line break before the `name=`.

Explanation:

```
<a               match the literal string '<a'
\r?\n            match \r\n or \n (line breaks)
name=Check       match the literal string 'name=Check '
\d+              match one or more digits
>                match the literal char '>'
```

Comment: Well explained.  If you want to be more specific and only match a certain number or range of digits you could just replace `\d+` with `\d{2}` or `\d{1,2}` for example to limit to 2 figures or between 1 and 2.